# Importing AWS secret in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables, spring-cloud, aws-secrets-manager, application.properties

I am trying to import secrets that I stored in AWS under `Credentials for other database`, into my application. I used `spring.config.import=aws-secretsmanager:/secret/test-service` for importing the secrets in my application.

I am able to access all the keys with correct values as such `${host}`, `${password}` and so on. However, I am getting incorrect value for `username` field. From what I can make of it, `${username}` is giving me the value of my system's user. How can I correct that? What is the correct way to access the keys?

Reference image:
[Secrets are stored as such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFEfm.png)

**EDIT:** I checked. `USERNAME` is an environment variable in my system. How do I get the application to use the username from secrets?

Comment: Are you able to retrieve the username from java code? I would pass the data as a model attribute retrieving it from a java class 

environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("aws.secret.manager", props));

Comment: Can you please check the update in the edit? I found the problem. What is the solution though?

Comment: I understand that thymeleaf does not receive by default the key as "username", that you have to "dig deeper" in the java side of your code... check this link: https://www.pranaybathini.com/aws-secrets-manager-password-rotation